# How to prioritize traffic using bridge and qdisc?

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge, qos

I'm trying to prioritize traffic over the Linux-based software bridge in my network. When I generate traffic locally (on the machine hosting the bridge), the traffic is correctly prioritized.
However, the "remote" traffic (from other nodes passing through the bridge) is not prioritized (same bandwidth distribution to all senders). 
Maybe someone knows why?

Bridge is set up as follows for the I350 network adapter (Linux 5.1.8-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 9 20:44:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
brctl addbr br0
ip link set dev enp1s0f0 promisc on
ip link set dev enp1s0f1 promisc on
ip link set dev enp1s0f2 promisc on
ip link set dev enp1s0f3 promisc on

brctl addif br0 enp1s0f0
brctl addif br0 enp1s0f1
brctl addif br0 enp1s0f2
brctl addif br0 enp1s0f3

ip link set dev br0 up

tc qdisc del dev enp1s0f0  root
tc qdisc add dev enp1s0f0  root prio
tc qdisc del dev enp1s0f1  root
tc qdisc add dev enp1s0f1  root prio
tc qdisc del dev enp1s0f2  root
tc qdisc add dev enp1s0f2  root prio
tc qdisc del dev enp1s0f3  root
tc qdisc add dev enp1s0f3  root prio

ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev br0
```

UDP traffic is generated with iperf3 and by setting the TOS field appropriately e.g.

```
Low-Prio Sender: iperf3 -c 192.168.1.140 -u -b 100m -S 0x2 -p 5201 -t 30
Hi-Prio Sender : iperf3 -c 192.168.1.140 -u -b 100m -S 0x0 -p 5202 -t 30
```

Prio map is left with default settings:  priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Just trying to understand the question: is there a tc qdisc ... prio rule somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I just corrected the question! (It was lost during editing)

Comment: Maybe it is a Layer 2 / Layer 3 issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have managed to find the solution :)

If you will encounter a similar issue use bridging network connections with proxy ARP (so enforce Layer 3) instead of the brctl

you may find a detailed tutorial here: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp

TOS allows "implementing quality of service (QoS) at the media access control (MAC) level" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q and mechanism as such is frequently classified as Layer 2 according to the OSI model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

However, as ToS/DSCP belong to the IP header it seems that they are processed on Layer 3 for incoming ("remote") data